# Convolution on noncommutative group algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, convolution

If $G$ is a non-Abelian locally compact group, and $f$ is in $L^1{(G)}$ and $u$ is in $L^{\infty}(G)$, and $f\ast u=0$ can it be concluded that $u\ast f=0$?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no, and one can find a counterexample already when $G$ is finite,
in fact when $G = S_3$ (or any finite non-abelian group).  [This MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58267/group-ring-and-left-zero-divisor) has a relevant discussion, and the following answer borrows from there:

If $G$ is finite, then the group ring $\mathbb C[G]$ (which coincides with 
both $L^1$ and $L^{\infty}$ for finite $G$) is a product of matrix rings.  If $G$ is non-abelian,
then at least one of these matrix rings consists of $n\times n$ matrices for $n > 1$.  But in such a matrix ring, there are elements $A$ and $B$ such that
$AB= 0$ but $BA \neq 0$.  Thus $\mathbb C[G]$ will contain elements $f$ and $u$
with the same property, namely such that $f*u = 0$ but $u*f \neq 0.$